# 'Template.exe' has exited with code 255 (0xff) when porting to Windows Store using Unity

Tags: windows-phone-8, unity-game-engine, windows-store-apps

I am trying to port an iPhone game to Windows mobile devices, I have already changed several classes to accommodate the .NET core differences. I have a clean build, however, when I run on my Surface, it exits after the opening Unity screen with the following:

```
'Template.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 
  'C:\WINDOWS\system32\WinMetadata\Windows.ApplicationModel.winmd'. Skipped 
  loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' 
  is enabled.
'Template.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 
  'C:\Users\ecarp_000\AppxLayouts\RLIC-UnityVS.Debug_ARM.ecarp_000\UnityPlayer.winmd'.
  Module was built without symbols.
The program '[1868] Template.exe' has exited with code 255 (0xff).
```

Comment: Try turning off 'Just My Code' in the debugger and seeing if anything interesting comes out.

Comment: After turning off 'Just My Code', I got the following:

'Template.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Template.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\WinMetadata\Windows.UI.Xaml.winmd'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Template.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded

Comment: 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Template.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\WinMetadata\Windows.ApplicationModel.winmd'. 
'Template.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Users\ecarp_000\AppxLayouts\RLIC-UnityVS.Debug_ARM.ecarp_000\UnityPlayer.winmd'. Module was built without symbols.
The program '[5568] Template.exe' has exited with code 255 (0xff).

Comment: When those crash, are you able to move up the stack trace? If so, try moving one step up the stack trace at a time and looking at the locals. Sometimes you can find more descriptive exception information in there.